# Access Application Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, configuration, directory

I am developing a webapplication using asp.net mvc 3.

In the solution I have a project for all the web/presentation things (models, views, controller) and in another project I have my services, daos and domainobject. now I created a config-file in my service-project with some settings. how can I access the file from my services?

If I don't set a path it uses the path of the asp.net exe.

Hope someone can help
Tobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to get proper path.
Or change Build action property of your config file to Embedded Resource ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx)). After that you will be able to retrieve file using [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)